# Найти значение в массвие по маске из второго массива

Tags: php

День добрый. Написал функцию, код работает, но время выполнения слишком велико. Прошу помощи оптимизировать код. Сама задача вот: есть массив c множеством элементов типа

```
$mass2 (
[120] => какойтотекст Пушкин какойтотекст,
[121] => какойтотекст Гоголь какойтотекст,
...)
```

и второй массив со множеством элементов типа

```
$mass1(
[17] => Пушкин,
[18] => Гоголь,
...)
```

.Число элементов исчисляется тысячами.Задача - получить ключ из первого массива (120, 121, ...), используя значения из второго. Притом, как в примере, Пушкин,Гоголь - дубликатов не имеют. написал код

```
foreach($mass1 as $key => $item){
    foreach($mass2 as $key2 => $item2){
        if(strripos ($item2,$item) != false){
            echo $key2.'<br>';

        }else{
    $no++;
        }
    }
}
```

Код на малой выброке работает, но на большой после 90 сек работы вылетает(Выполняю в командной PHP-строке Битрикса). Можно ли как то оптимизоварть его?
Спасибо.

Comment: массивы одной длины? или во `$mass1` строк меньше? каков объем данных в реальных массивах, по сколько строк, и какой длины тексты? какую версию пхп пользуете, и сколько это выполняется, если тайм лимит отключить? Может ли гоголю, напримре, соответствовать несколько строк? или только одна?

Comment: *как в примере, Пушкин,Гоголь - дубликатов не имеют.* Имеется в виду, что нет такого элемента в $mass2, который соответствует сразу двум элементам из $mass1?

Comment: Требуется ли поиск совпадения строго слов (что бы под этим термином не понималось), или ищутся произвольные подстроки?

Comment: в $mass2 около 290 000 значений, в $mass1 около 8 000. "Как в примере, Пушкин,Гоголь - дубликатов не имеют" - да, таких элементов $mass1, чтобы в $mass2 их было больше 1, отсутствуют.

Comment: Если быть точным, в маске не слово(хотя не исключено, а фразы типа "Очки солнцезащитные «Тополь»"), во втором массиве соответственно есть значение: " куча текста   Очки солнцезащитные «Тополь»  куча текста".Конечная задача - получить ключ тех элементов из  $mass1, где есть нужная фраза.

Comment: вы для начала циклы местами поменяйте, большой массив снаружи чтобы был. а вхождения во внутреннем. Когда входждение находите, удаляйте его из массива и к следующей итерации внешнего переходите.

Comment: Версия пхп -  7.1.19, местами поменял, добавил unset найденного значения, время выполнения больше 90 сек. К сожалению, увеличить сейчас нет возможности. Едиственная идея - разбить больший массив на части, и поэтапно выполнять.

Comment: `break` то не забыли ?

Comment: и почему вы не можете `set_time_limit(0)` вызвать? запрещено что ли? 290тыс строк вобще прилично памяти съест, вчера вон заполнение 200к чисел 30 метров съело :)

Comment: @teran Спасибо! Вынес обработку в отдельный файл, поставил set_time_limit(600) и за 417 сек обработало!

Comment: @НикитаКолесников вы еще обратите внимание, что используете функцию `strRipos`. а не `stripos`. Ваша возвращает последнее вхождение. Может, конечно при одном вхождении подстроки и не существенно, но тем не менее.